# Firefox Furigana Injector on Debian

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, debian

I'm using Iceweasel (un/rebranded Firefox) 3.5.9 on Debian (amd64).  I want to use the "Furigana Injector" plugin.

I installed it via the Tools -> Add-ons menu item (version 1.3), and restarted Firefox.  Unfortunately, when I click the button, it only says: "The 'SimpleMecab' XPCOM component could not be loaded." in a dialog box, several dozen times (!).

I found a Debian package "libmecab1", but installing it didn't help.  Is there some "mecab" package I can install that will make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are [not the only one](http://code.google.com/p/furigana-injector/issues/detail?id=29&can=1&q=XPCOM) who has had problems on a 64-bit Debian based distro (which is an [unsupported configuration](http://code.google.com/p/furigana-injector/wiki/LinuxVersion) for this Add-On).  The libraries were compiled with 32-bit Fedora Core 9, so some incompatibilities in the binaries are likely the problem.  In the issue linked above the Add-On author suggest trying the [newer version](http://furigana-injector.googlecode.com/files/furiganainjector.2-0.xpi) which doesn't rely on a binary component.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but Version 2 is currently useless because it depends on being able to access a furigana server, and there is only one furigana server in the whole world, and that has recently been down (to be clear: it was down every time I tried in April / May 2010). Much better to have the furigana dictionary inside the addon, like in Version 1.

Unfortunately, you're completely out of luck with this addon unless the author decides to add 64-bit support to Version 1, but that seems unlikely as he seems to have dropped the ball and run off with totally furigana-server-dependent Version 2.